# Mysql Distinct select with replace

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following mySql select statement it returns the below result and battling to get the result I am after.

```
 select `tvshow`.`idShow` AS `idShow`,`tvshow`.`c00` AS `ShowName`,
         if(count(distinct `episode`.`c12`),
         count(distinct `episode`.`c12`),0) AS `TotalSeasons`,
        if(count(`episode`.`c12`),count(`episode`.`c12`),0) AS `TotalEpisodeCount`
    from
        ((((`tvshow`
        left join `tvshowlinkpath` ON ((`tvshowlinkpath`.`idShow` = `tvshow`.`idShow`)))
        left join `path` ON ((`path`.`idPath` = `tvshowlinkpath`.`idPath`)))
        left join `episode` ON ((`episode`.`idShow` = `tvshow`.`idShow`)))
        left join `files` ON ((`files`.`idFile` = `episode`.`idFile`)))
    group by `tvshow`.`idShow`
    having (count(`episode`.`c12`) > 0)
```

**Select Result**

[image: Select Result]

I am trying to get a 4th column that would have the seasons listed in it e.g "Season 1,Season 2,Season 3"

I can get the the data I need by running the following select

`select distinct c12 from episode where idShow = 1`

It returns the following.

[image]

So i thought I could use the replace to change the results to read "Season1" but not sure how to get it to just return one string containing "Seasin1,Season2,Season3" and then add it to the select statement at the top of the view and bring it all together?

**The Result I am trying to get**(used Photoshop for this just so you could get the idea)

[image]

Comment: can you show the schema of the tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `GROUP_CONCAT(episode.c12)` as additional column:

```
select `tvshow`.`idShow` AS `idShow`,`tvshow`.`c00` AS `ShowName`,
         if(count(distinct `episode`.`c12`),
         count(distinct `episode`.`c12`),0) AS `TotalSeasons`,
        if(count(`episode`.`c12`),count(`episode`.`c12`),0) AS `TotalEpisodeCount`,
        `GROUP_CONCAT(episode.c12)` as `Seasons`
    from
        ((((`tvshow`
        left join `tvshowlinkpath` ON ((`tvshowlinkpath`.`idShow` = `tvshow`.`idShow`)))
        left join `path` ON ((`path`.`idPath` = `tvshowlinkpath`.`idPath`)))
        left join `episode` ON ((`episode`.`idShow` = `tvshow`.`idShow`)))
        left join `files` ON ((`files`.`idFile` = `episode`.`idFile`)))
    group by `tvshow`.`idShow`
    having (count(`episode`.`c12`) > 0)
```

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat for the documentation of this MySQL specific function.

Comment: Ok thanks that almost work i jsut had to change it to `GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(episode.c12))` so that it returned 1,3,2 for example because `GROUP_CONCAT(episode.c12)` returned 111111111,22222,333 for example, just need to do the order and replace part now